# Rails - Want to build a profile for user after using Devise gem as sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise for registration. But I want to build a profile for user so that where user can fill their info. 
I want a single for profile for user but whenever new_profile_path another profile is created for that user, I want to avoid user to go to new_profile_path or create new profile after 1 profile is created.

here is the code

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile
  has_many :statuses
end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates_associated :user
end
```

profiles_controller.erb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :find_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

respond_to :html

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  def new
      @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    @profile.user_id = current_user.id
    @profile.save
    respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @profile.update(profile_params)
    respond_with(@profile)
  end


  private

    def find_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birth_date,                  
        :gender, :bio, :personal_website, :linkedin_profile,     :facebook_profile,
           :mobile_no, :telephone_no)
  end
end
```

This is the current code for creating Profile for user. But every time a profile is created for user through new_profile_path. How can I avoid it?

Thanks in advance for giving your time.

Comment: Don't call @profile = Profile.new then in the new method. Just leave it empty. The only reason you need the new method is to have it render the corresponding page for you.

Comment: But it won't allow user to create a single profile.

Comment: I am sorry. I figured you would be using JSON also. Have never done .erb applications my self so I never use the new method really.

Comment: Its ok! But thanks for giving a try to help out and giving your time.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

```
# in User model

has_one :profile
before_create :build_profile, unless: :profile
```

Alternatively:

```
# in User model

has_one :profile
after_create :create_profile, unless: :profile
```

The conditional `unless: :profile` is there so that it doesn't overwrite a `profile` that was already added before the user was created.

Answer (score 0):

When your using associations, you have to use build instead of new.... In your Profile controller...

```
def new 
  @profile = current_user.build_profile
end

def create
  @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
  if @profile.save
    flash[:success] = "Profile saved"
    redirect_to current_user_path
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error"
    render: new
  end
end
```

This will make sure that only one profile is created for each user...

```
def edit
  @profile = current_user.profile.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @profile = current_user.profile.find(params[:id])
  if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
    flash[:success] = "Successfully updated"    # Optional
    redirect_to user_path
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error"       # Optional
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Do I need to make changes in **new** method or also in **create** method, as it is showing undefined method build when I made changes in new method

Comment: Can you please suggest me the edit required to made in create method as I am new to build method and there is error while using it.

Comment: Please see the update answer above.... let me know if it works. If its working, then post it as right answer. Thanks

Comment: Don't know about the issue. I have updated the code to build there is error undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: at new method and error is same "undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass "